# Text Transposing in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Needed your help on this.  Looking for a shell script which can convert the follwing input file to the desired output. We use Bash shell

Input File (.txt) contains:

```
,,,,Jan_1,Jan_2,Jan_3,Jan_4,Jan_5,.........Jan_30,Feb_1,Feb,2...Dec_31
a,b,c,d,88,89,91,.........(365 numbers)
e,f,g,h,34,23,17,..........(365 numbers)
i,j,k,l,52,63,86,.........(365 numbers)
```

Expected Output:

```
a,b,c,d,Jan_1,88
a,b,c,d,Jan_2,89
a,b,c,d,Jan_3,91
....
....
a,b,c,d,Jan_31,656
a,b,c,d,Feb_1,23
....
....
a,b,c,d,Dec_31,656
e,f,g,h,Jan_1,34
e,f,g,h,Jan_2,23
e,f,g,h,Jan_3,17
...
...
...
e,f,g,h,Aug_3,454
....
...
e,f,g,h,Dec_31,878    
i,j,k,l,Jan_1,52
i,j,k,l,Jan_2,63
i,j,k,l,Jan_3,86
 .....
 ....
 i,j,k,l,Dec_31,23
```

Number of records in the input file is around 13k. 
Please advice.

I thought of storing the first line into an array and then considering the first four columns as a matrix and then do a cross multiplying to get the effect of transpose.

/

```
/ stored the first line in an array  array1
// From second line using this to get the matrix
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do


    ## Unable to multiply this arr with array1

     echo ${arr[@]:0:4}

done < 'working file.
```

txt'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: On Stackoverflow, your question needs to have your attempt to solve the problem, then where you got stuck, then your question as reflected in your title.  Please go back and edit this question so it is presented that way.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help fixing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43750058/edit) and I'll gleefully retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

`Awk` may help

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR>1{
 for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
   for(j=1;j<4;j++){
   printf("%s,",$j)
   }
 printf("Jan_%d,%s",i,$(i+j))
 print ""
 }
}' filename
a,b,c,Jan_1,10
a,b,c,Jan_2,20
a,b,c,Jan_3,30
e,f,g,Jan_1,11
e,f,g,Jan_2,21
e,f,g,Jan_3,31
i,j,k,Jan_1,12
i,j,k,Jan_2,22
i,j,k,Jan_3,32
```

Comment: Note that as other comments mention, the work you've done is mandatory in your question. Next time, please add your code snippet too when you ask question. Answers without genuine attempt to solve the problem is generally not encouraged in SO.

Comment: thanks @sjsam. But the challenge is the numbers can vary. I just gave those numbers as illustration. As well the number of columns is 365 days (ex:- Jan_1, Jan_2,Jan_3,....Feb_1,....Feb_28,..... Dec_1,Dec_31).